RAID 1 vs RAID 5 for single block read
will the speed of single block read of RAID-1 be faster than RAID-5?
can a single block be read in parallel in RAID-1?
I think not because if reading in parallel sequence had to be maintained.
or will the OS handle maintaining correct order after read is done?
or will the speed will be same for a single block and only faster if we read multiple random blocks in RAID-1 in parallel?
